# How to play youtube and vimeo videos in html5 jw player

Tags: html, video, jwplayer, vimeo

I don't know how to play Vimeo and YouTube videos using HTML5 JW Player on iPhones, iPods, iPads and other non-Flash machines.

For example, I have a URL http://vimeo.com/43064629 (Vimeo) or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsrhJp7Dwy0 (YouTube). I want to play the above video on iPhones, iPods, iPads and non-Flash devices. Can this be done using JW Player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't support Vimeo files, but YouTube should be supported.

A simple JW Player setup like this will work in Flash/HTML5 - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29236/basic-youtube-stream

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer Do you support vimeo now? Please direct me to the page where I can get the list of supported platforms.

Comment: We do not support Vimeo. http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support

Answer (score 0):

JWPlayer might not support Vimeo but Vimeo supports third party players.

https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-How-do-I-use-a-third-party-player-with-Vimeo-PRO-or-Vimeo-Business-?flash_digest=8045c7a26dd56a8bb21f6cae3588f9f45ac3a34e

Just copy the provided link into your embedded video properties.

1. Copy the link from Vimeo (click the settings button on one of your videos then click 'Video file')
2. Embed a JW Player into your website using the copied URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeAjliRTEMI